# Integrate external fingerprint sensor in web app authentication

Tags: node.js, authentication, architecture, biometrics

I am currently working on my final year project, and one of the tasks I am struggling with is integrating biometrics in the authentication system of a web app. I have gone through many readings, questions and blog posts, but none of them seems to deal with the exact same issue.

**The problem:** I have an external fingerprint sensor (GT21F32 https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14518). Is there any way I could use this sensor in order to get a user to authenticate on my web app?

**My thinking process:**

1. have the user input username/password in the login fields;
2. once they hit login button the server creates a *SESSION* (**call it x**) in which they are prompted to put their finger on the sensor;
3. if everything goes well (data check aganist internal sensor store returns a valid match), user is signed in (mix this with jwt auth?);
4. similar flow for registering

**Regarding *SESSION* **x****:

- I was considering during that time my authentication API could communicate with an API that wraps the functionality of my sensor
- e.g: call a *readFingerprint()* or *searchForFingerprint()* function that I implement, which in turn communicates locally with the hardware using it's SDK protocols
- I was considering writing this fingerprint API as a node package so that I can use node with Javascript

Please offer me some guidance, since my project supervisor does not really provide much help, and I feel I have exhausted all the possible sources of information.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: why would you need username/password if you could have `fingerprint` auth?

Comment: @sonkatamas I want my app to provide additional functionality if someone registers with a fingerprint too